# cannot find symbol ReactFeatureFlags.enableKeyDownEvents = false

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, symbols

I'm developing android tv by `react-native-tvOs`

Until a few days ago everything was ok, But now I get this error :

[image: command error]

[image]